# How to count the number of rows which contain a cell containing specific text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am super new to Stack Overflow so if I do anything wrong, let me know.

Essentially, I am trying to create a formula which will look at a row and check if any of its cells contain specific text and, if so, count the number of rows which do. The issue I am having is that I am checking the cells not for if they equal the exact text, just if they contain it.

If any additional information or context is needed, which I am sure it is, please just let me know what you need.

Comment: _"I do anything wrong, let me know. [...] The issue I am having is..."_ Please [edit] the question and include your current formula. This makes it possible for others to either tell you what's wrong with your formula/code/etc or suggest a different solution entirely.

Comment: I always use this website when I have any excel questions, it never lets me down. Tons of examples for basically any problem. https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for any value and not any specific value then You can use CountA formula in this case as COUNTA simply counts the number of cells that contain any value (that is, cells that are not blank) but If you are looking for a specific text in a row then you can use COUNTIF formula.

Answer (score 0):

If for example the data in a row in is `A1:H1`, you could use `OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND,<search text>,A1:H1))))`.  `FIND` is case-sensitive.  In some earlier versions on Excel, you may need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.